# SQL Database split column

Tags: php, sql, email

I have made a table in phpMyAdmin where 250 emails are saved, those emails are used to send a mail which I made in PHPMailer class. I need the mails to be divided over 5 days so in this case 50 mails a day.

They are going to be auto implemented via our website if you signup the email is added via a simple query into the database so if a new email is added it needs to be put in the first group. I tried to make a day count 1 through 5 but i don't know how I am going to add that day count automatically.

If you have a idea to add upon that idea or have a whole new approach it would be amazing.
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: If I understood correctly, when a new email is added, you want it to be part of the group that is sent first? Meaning that the 50th email from the first group will then be moved into the second group?

Comment: @El_Vanja Yes exactly

Comment: Let's say that the first group was already sent. Should the new email then be added into the group that's next up for sending or still be added to the first group and only receive the email next week when a new round begins?

Comment: @El_Vanja Let's say I have 100 mail addresses those email addresses need to be divided by 5 so the systems sends 20 mails a day to those people who signed up. If a new one gets added he gets added to the first group because you can divide 1 email. If then 4 more sign up then there are going to be 21 people who receive this mail. And yes to answer your question but i just wanted to be clear with the question.

Comment: Sounds like adding one more (boolean) column to the email table which marks it as sent or not would solve this. Then you could fetch the remaining addresses and divide that number with the number of days left (so you'd divide by 5 on Monday, 4 on Tuesday etc. until Friday when you'd send all the remaining ones).

Comment: @El_Vanja I like this idea but then how would I divide them?

Comment: @El_Vanja Nevermind I read your message wrong. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. Ping me if you run into issues with the implementation.

Comment: @El_Vanja Hey i'm running into a problem. How do i switch that boolean if I run the query

Comment: Switch? In what sense? Update its value?

Comment: @El_Vanja yeah update it's value to 1 if for example the first set of emails is sent out.

Comment: Well, while you're sending the emails, you can run a query to update it if the sending was successful (for each individual mail - makes more sense than updating the whole group). And then you can have a cron job to reset the value to 0 for all the emails that runs on the weekends.

Comment: Okay that makes sense thanks!